# How to implement react icon properly with useState hook?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-hooks, react-icons

On React, I attempted making a feature to let user can see active feedback on screen by changing its icon when they click it.

How can I let it change to another icon (e.g. from Box to BoxChecked) once I click it?

note: I know this code line is the problem...(sob)

```
<img src={click} alt="icon" onClick={handleClick} />
```

App.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import './App.css'
import { GrCheckbox as Box }  from 'react-icons/gr'
import { GrCheckboxSelected as BoxChecked } from 'react-icons/gr' 

export default function App() {
  const [icon, setIcon] = useState(false);
  const [click, setClick] = useState(Box);
  
  function handleClick() {
    setIcon(!icon); 
    icon ? setClick(Box) : setClick(BoxChecked);
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <img src={click} alt="icon" onClick={handleClick} />
        <p>Clicked {click} times</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Storing a component in state is not recommended. Use condition to set `src`.

```
    <img src={icon ? Box : BoxChecked} alt="icon" onClick={handleClick} />
```

Change handler to this

```
function handleClick() {
    setIcon(prevIcon => !prevIcon); 
}
```

or better

```
const handleClick = useCallback(() => {
      setIcon(prevIcon => !prevIcon); 
}, []);
```

Comment: I think this is the correct answer and you could remove all the click related code, in my answer I explained why it was not working, but if you should follow any approach I would go for @kiranvj suggestion

Answer (score 1):

`useState` is async so you don't have the value of icon immediately after the execution of `setIcon` in your handler.
You need to put the `setClick` call in a `useEffect` hook:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
    icon ? setClick(Box) : setClick(BoxChecked);
}, [icon]);

function handleClick() {
    setIcon(!icon); 
}
```

This effect will be executed when icon changes because it is added to the `useEffect`'s dependency array. Have a look at the docs for more info:
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html